# Search by self-referencing navigation property EF Core

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I've got following POCO:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool UnderProcessing { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public Event Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select all events meeting criteria below:

```
context.Events
    .Include(ev => ev.Parent)
    .Where(ev => (ev.ParentId != null && ev.Parent.UnderProcessing) || ev.ParentId == null) 
    .OrderByDescending(ev => ev.CreatedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Data in database is:

```
Event: id = 1, UnderProcessing  = true, CreatedDate = 15.03.2020, ParentId = null
Event: id = 2, UnderProcessing  = false, CreatedDate = 16.03.2020, ParentId = 1
```

But instead of returning event with id = 2, cause it's first row after ordering in desc, it always gives me Event with id = 1. How that's possible, it seems EF Core skips condition for self-referencing navigation property?
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: The second record has `ParentId` 1 (not `null`) and at the same time `UnderProcessing` is `false` not `true` so on `.Where` it naturally skips this record as it doesn't meet any of the two conditions

Comment: @Fabjan No, first condition check that parentId not null, which is 1 and then go to parent entity and check it for underprocessing which is true. So condition are met